# PHP: Extract HTML data from website

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to to extract NAME, ADDRESS and EMAIL from the website

`http://agentquery.com/agent.aspx?agentid=13`

How can I do this using file_get_contents() in PHP

For e.g

`$abc  = file_get_content("http://agentquery.com/agent.aspx?agentid=13");`

Now how can I extract NAME, EMAIL and ADDRESS from it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with `file_get_contents()` and some regex processing. You must ensure you have [fopen URL wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) enabled in PHP.ini

You need to grab the page, then find unique string to parse on. This is to get the name:

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents('http://agentquery.com/agent.aspx?agentid=13');

// name will be inside a span ctl00_Agent1_lblName, store it in $agent_name
preg_match("/<span id=\"ctl00_Agent1_lblName\".*span>/", $page, $agent_name);

// display agent name matches
print_r($agent_name);
```

Comment: Looks good but its giving an array with nothing inside for e.g I echod `echo count($agent_name);` count is zero

Comment: got it.. it's ID not CLASS..

Comment: Yeah sorry, just edited my answer. Having one of those days...

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy just use simple html dom class and you can get the required values if you know selectors in css, jQuery

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/