# waiting for the website to change something

Tags: web, web-testing

I am a student and in the school website, what I want to do is that I want to busy wait on the certain URL and check if the class i want to register for is open or not. I was wondering if there was a way to constantly check on the website(busy waiting or otherwise) to see if the class is open or not. There is a table Rem where it shows the number of places remaining in the User Interface.

Also what language would you use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. but for that you will probably need to create a script that fetches the value of data from that table.
So something like web scraping should work.

I would definately use php for this stuff.

Google web scraping and you can code the script.

I am not sure if this is the exact thing that will help you, but what you need to do is something similar - [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106456/php-extract-html-data-from-website)